# How to modify \part names?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, parts, naming

I'd like to modify the way parts are named, into my toc, in the same way they are named in the body of my document:

*Première partie*

For the first part.

*Deuxième partie*

For the second part, and so on. How could I do that? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% can be removed with an uptodate TeX distribution
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Didot}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter
  \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Éléments d'analyse}

\chapter{Définitions}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should take a look at `titlesec` and the `fmtcount` package, which has an `\ordinal{counter}`command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the KOMA-Script command `\addparttocentry`:

```latex
\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}
      {\csname ordinal\romannumeral\value{part}\endcsname\space\partnameord}% copied from french.ldf
      {#2}%
    }%
}%
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocdynnumwidth]{part}% adjust the space for part number in TOC
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[%fontsize=11pt,% default
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Didot}% I do not have this font
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter
  \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}
      {\csname ordinal\romannumeral\value{part}\endcsname\space\partnameord}% copied from french.ldf
      {#2}%
    }%
}%
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocdynnumwidth]{part}% adjust the space for part number in TOC 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Éléments d'analyse}\label{p}
\chapter{Définitions}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]